# How to use config server to serve resource bundles to micro services

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config

We are using Spring Cloud config server in our project which has multiple micro services. With config server in place, we are now storing all properties for all the micro services in a central git repository. Each micro service is able to pull his own properties file based on application name and profiles. 
We are trying to store our resource bundles in the central repository and have config-server serve these resource bundles to micro services. Our resource bundles include properties files like messages_en.properties, messages_es.properties, messages_cn.properties, etc. We are able to load an resource bundle to config server using profile but it is acting as properties file. 
We are using resource bundle in velocity template for GUI. Like

```
    <div class="top-content">
                        <div class="intro-box">
                            <h1 class="font-light">#**springMessageText("welcome.text2","W**elcome to <br/><strong>Our Website!")</strong>
</h1>
```

Could someone suggest how they have done it ? or any link to use config server for loading n using resource bundle?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue, I worked round it by deriving a new sub class of `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` and overriding `protected List<String> calculateFilenamesForLocale(String basename, Locale locale)`

The overridden method adds the locale variants to the base URL so for the base url http://localhost:8888/app-default and Locale.ENGLISH we get

- http://localhost:8888/app-default
- http://localhost:8888/app_en-default
- http://localhost:8888/app_en_GB-default

It assumes the last index of '-' in the basename is the start of the profile.

Comment: Can you please add more details on this? like How did you do this? Does this mean that i18n is supported out of spring cloud config server? If yes then please post some code example too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Spring Cloud Config server for properties that change between environments (dev / staging / prod / ....) or for configurable properties such as thread pool size, DB connection pool size, ..... but not for message bundles since adding / renaming keys also assumes a template would need to be updated or added requiring a new artifact / binary to be built.

Comment: What, if anything, would you suggest as an alternative? I'm looking into this domain right now and wondering if I should create a micro-service that handles message bundles/localization so that we can have a single location for getting this information.